Reflection and Lorentz-transformation
I have some difficulties to prove the following
Let F be a vector space of dimension n+1 equipped with
a quadratic form of Sylvester type (—n,l). Any Lorentz transformation $\sigma$ of $F$ is
the product of at most n+1 reflections of the type $\tau_{c}(x)=x-2\frac{\left\langle x,c\right\rangle}{\left\langle c,c\right\rangle}c$ where $\left\langle c,c\right\rangle=-1 $.
I thought about induction over the dimnesion $n$, but can i not pick an orthonormalbasis $e_{1},...,e_{n+1}$ of $F$ and show that there exists a vector $c_{1}$ such that $\tau_{c_{1}}(e_{1})=f(e_{1})$. Then pick another reflection such that $\tau_{c_{2}}(\tau_{c_{1}}(e_{1}))=f(e_{1})$ and $\tau_{c_{2}}(\tau_{c_{1}}(e_{2}))=f(e_{2})$ and so on.
I need some help to proof that such vectors $c_{n}$ exist, and that $\tau_{c_{i}}(...(\tau_{c_{2}}(\tau_{c_{1}}(e_{1}))=f(e_{1})$ and so on.

Is $f$ the same as $\sigma$?

Oh yes its the same sorry.
